# How to update a string shown in a Holoviz panel?

Tags: python, string, holoviz, holoviz-panel

I have a variable `currentValue` of type string. This variables changes as the user interacts with the panel. I want to show the updated string to the user, but I only managed to display the initial value (which is nothing, because I initialize with “”).

How do I update a string shown in a Holoviz panel?